# scp with Python3 subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, scp

Trying to run an scp command to copy only the content of a directory (not the directory itself) with subprocess i found some problems with wildcards:

```
scp_result = subprocess.run([
    "scp",
    "./tosend/archive_*",
    "{0}@{1}:{2}/.".format("usr", "192.168.1.2", "/home/usr/scpdir")
], shell=True)
```

Even using the shell=True option that should allow wildcards i get the error message:

```
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
       [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
       [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

The CompletedProcess is:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['scp', './tosend/archive_*', 'usr@192.168.1.2:/home/usr/scpdir/.'], returncode=1)
```

and seem to contain the right arguments. Trying to copy a single file without the wildcard works perfectly.

Comment: Might be related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27422/105894

Comment: besides shell=True works better with a string, not a list IIRC.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre there was a typo on the question, the "/" was placed correctly

Comment: @MarcoBenetti ok, understand that those typos make it more difficult to answer/"believe" that your problem is real. Now that it's fixed, try with a simple string (not list) since shell=True works best with that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre passing a string instead of a list fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: cool. You can read the duplicate link. I wasn't going to answer that, since it's a well known Unix/Linux issue.